# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Commit Failed since the group is rebalanced

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have got the `CommitFailedException` for some time-consuming Spring Cloud Stream applications. I know to fix this issue I need to set the `max.poll.records` and `max.poll.interval.ms` to match my expectations for the time it takes to process the batch. However, I am not quite sure how to set it for consumers in Spring Cloud Stream.

Exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records. at
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:808) at
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:691) at
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1416) at 
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1377) at 
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitIfNecessary(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1554) at 
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processCommits(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1418) at 
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:739) at 
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:700) at 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Moreover, how can I ensure this situation won't happen at all? Or alternatively, how can I inject some sort of roll-back in the case of this exception? The reason is I am doing some other external works and once it is finished I publish the output message accordingly. Therefore, if the message cannot get published due to any issues after the work was done on the external system, I have to revert it back (some sort of atomic transaction over Kafka publish and other external systems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set arbitrary Kafka properties either at the binder level [documentation here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_configuration_options)

> **spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumerProperties**
>
> Key/Value map of arbitrary Kafka client consumer properties. In addition to support known Kafka consumer properties, unknown consumer properties are allowed here as well. Properties here supersede any properties set in boot and in the configuration property above.
>
> Default: Empty map.

e.g. `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumerProperties.max.poll.records=10`

Or at the binding level [documentation here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties).

> **spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.configuration**
>
> Map with a key/value pair containing generic Kafka consumer properties. In addition to having Kafka consumer properties, other configuration properties can be passed here. For example some properties needed by the application such as spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.configuration.foo=bar.
>
> Default: Empty map.

e.g. `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.configuration.max.poll.records=10`

You can get notified of commit failures by adding an `OffsetCommitCallback` to the listener container's `ContainerProperties` and setting `syncCommits` to `false`. To customize the container and its properties, add a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean to the application.

**EDIT**

Async commit callback...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So57970152Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So57970152Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<byte[], byte[]>> customizer() {
        return (container, dest, group) -> {
            container.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
            container.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(false);
            container.getContainerProperties().setCommitCallback((map, ex) -> {
                if (ex == null) {
                    System.out.println("Successful commit for " + map);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Commit failed for " + map + ": " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            });
            container.getContainerProperties().setClientId("so57970152");
        };
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("input", "foo".getBytes());
        };
    }

}
```

Manual commits (sync)...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So57970152Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So57970152Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<byte[], byte[]>> customizer() {
        return (container, dest, group) -> {
            container.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
            container.getContainerProperties().setClientId("so57970152");
        };
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) Acknowledgment ack) {
        System.out.println(in);
        try {
            ack.acknowledge(); // MUST USE MANUAL_IMMEDIATE for this to work.
            System.out.println("Commit successful");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Commit failed " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("input", "foo".getBytes());
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate more on the approach you have mentioned to have a bean to get notified by the commit failure?

Comment: You can also use manual commits to detect the exception. I added examples of both techniques to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set you heartbeat interval to less that 1/3rd of your session timeout. If the broker cannot determine if your consumer is alive, it will initiate a partition rebalance among the remaining consumers. So you have a heartbeat thread to inform the broker that the consumer is alive in case the application is taking a bit longer to process. Change these in your consumer configs:

```
heartbeat.interval.ms

session.timeout.ms
```

Try increasing the session timeout if it does not work. You have to fiddle around with these values.